# Iterations of a bash script to run in parallel

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that looks like below.
$TOOL is another script which runs 2 times with different inputs(VAR1 and VAR2).

```
#Iteration 1
${TOOL} -ip1 ${VAR1} -ip2 ${FINAL_PML}/$1$2.txt -p ${IP} -output_format ${MODE} -o ${FINAL_MODE_DIR1} 
rename mods mode_c_ ${FINAL_MODE_DIR1}/*.xml 

#Iteration 2
${TOOL} -ip1 ${VAR2} -ip2 ${FINAL_PML}/$1$2.txt -p ${IP} -output_format ${MODE} -o ${FINAL_MODE_DIR2} 
rename mods mode_c_ ${FINAL_MODE_DIR2}/*.xml
```

Can I make these 2 iterations in parallel inside a bash script without submitting it in a queue?

Comment: Look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-command-or-code-in-parallel-in-bash-shell-under-linux-or-unix/ .

Comment: `without submitting it in a queue?` What queue? "submitting" how? `Can I make....` yes, you can. What research did you do? Before continuing - check your script with https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0):

If I read this right, what you want is to run them in *background*.
c.f. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/

More importantly, if you are going to be writing scripts, **PLEASE** read the following closely:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001